# Initial rotation of surface plot

Tags: matlab

Without modifying an array of data used to generate a surface chart is there a way to control the initial rotation of the plot? I.e. - when I run this command:

```
surf(Y, 'LineStyle', ':', 'LineWidth', .1);
```

`[0 0 0]` is located in the front corner.

[image: Default surf rotation]

I'd like to rotate the chart such that `[0 0 0]` appears initially in the left/bottom/rear of the chart, equivalent to dragging the mouse to the left so the chart turns 90 degrees, or clockwise looking down from the top.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup... use [`view`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/view.html).  Given that your figure is open, this allows you to specify the azimuthal and elevational rotation of your figure.
This is defined in degrees.

Azimuthal rotation can roughly be equated to longitudinal rotation, while elevational would be the latitude. The latitude has a range from -90 to +90 degrees where -90 is where you're looking from the bottom and +90 would look overhead and the longitudinal has a range from -180 to +180 degrees, where the positive and negative values denote clockwise and counterclockwise rotations.

The default viewing angle for a 3D plot assumes that the azimuth is -37.5 degrees while the elevational is 30 degrees, or in other words, MATLAB does this right before displaying your figure:

```
view(-37.5, 30);
```

In your case, you want to rotate with the azimuth by 90 degrees.  As such, once your figure is open, with respect to the default 3D view, do either this:

```
view(52.5, 30); %// Azimuth = -37.5+90
```

or

```
view(-127.5, 30); %// Azimuth - -37.5-90
```

This will rotate the azimuth either counter-clockwise or clockwise by 90 degrees.

Comment: Thanks rayryeng. I guess you been doin' this awhile?! Anyway, view works better than rotate which I found but seemed to mess up the values on the axes.

Comment: @LGTrader cool! Glad I could help! Yes I've been using it for quite a while as you've noticed :)